# Using customized setter/getter and initializing the property for a swift date

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have a class called `Trip` which has an `NSDate` property called `date`. My desire is to make sure that the `date` property always has the time value set to the beginning of the day. I do this by:

1. Creating an `NSCalendar` constant called `calendar` so that I can use the `startOfDayForDate` method to reset the date value.
2. Creating a custom setter method for the `date` property that calls the startOfDayForDate method.

However, I want to initialize the `date` property to the start of today's date.

The code that I have so far is shown below.

```
class Trip {

    private let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

    var date: NSDate {
        get {
            return self.date
        }
        set {
            self.date = calendar.startOfDayForDate(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

This code a) doesn't initialize the date property and b) (I discovered) results in an infinite loop when the setter is called. Upon further research, I believe that customized getters/setters are *strictly computed*, right?

How do I accomplish what I mentioned earlier:

a.) making sure that sets to the `date` property reset to the start of the day and

b.) initializing the `date` property to the start of today's date?

Comment: When you say the start of the day, what do you mean? Do you want it to return the start of today, or the start of the calendar?

Comment: I want a consistent time for my dates to ensure proper date comparisons. Therefore, I mean the start of the day (i.e., zero hour, zero minutes, zero seconds). My understanding is that the "startOfDateForDate" method will provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have a date that will always be the start of the date. Replace your current `date` variable with this:

```
private var privateDate = NSDate()
var date: NSDate {
    get {
        return privateDate
    }
    set {
        privateDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(newValue)
    }
}
```

There may be a slightly better way to do this, but I'm guessing your application won't have tens of thousands of your Trip class, so you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I came to the same conclusion that I need to have two variables as you demonstrate with `privateDate` and `date`. I could initialize the `privateDate` property with `(NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!).startOfDayForDate(NSDate())` too.